# Adding variable to a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am not good at C programming. I need some inputs on how to add a variable to Structure that will point to the Structure variables. I am not sure if this sentence makes any sense to you. I will try to explain it.
My struct looks like (This is the structure for string maze data):

```
struct maze {
    char ** mazeValue;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows, numcolumns;
    int initdir;
};
```

Here `starty` represents row in maze and `startx` represents column in maze. 
While looping through maze for finding path, I need to assign cost to each move. So if I start at `[0][2]` and move to `[1][2]`, I need to assign cost 1 to the location [1][2] and so on. How can I achieve this by storing right cost for right location? For this how can I add a variable to my `struct` so that while printing the maze output I can also print the cost for that path.?

Comment: The maze in your structure is a 2-dimensional array of characters: `char **mazeValue`. That needs to be a 2-dimensional array of structures, so that you can store more information about each location in the maze.

Comment: @user3386109 - Can you elaborate it more please? I am not much familiar in C.

Comment: What does `mazeValue` looks like? If it has, say 0 for blocked and 1 for free, you could use the rest of values as the cost and keep your `struct` unchanged, except for maybe a bigger type (although, I'd change the `char**` to `char*` and do the indexing myself, so instead of `m->mazeValue[i][j]`, you have `m->mazeValue[i*m->numcolumns+j]`).

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As @user3386109 suggests in the comments:

> The maze in your structure is a 2-dimensional array of characters: char **mazeValue. That needs to be a 2-dimensional array of structures, so that you can store more information about each location in the maze.

So, you have to create another structure to store more information about each location in the maze.

Like:

```
struct slot
{
 char mazeValue;
 int cost;
};
```

And then change the type of `mazeValue`in your original `struct` to `slot` like:

```
struct maze
{
 struct slot ** maze;
 int startx, starty;
 int numrows, numcolumns;
 int initdir;
};
```

Now you can access the `mazeValue` and `cost` for the slot at location `[1][2]` like:

```
maze[1][2].cost = //whatever;
```

and similarly:

```
maze[1][2].mazeValue = //whatever;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this.

Comment: @user6344678 what is different from my answer?

Comment: Read both you of them closely and you will notice.

Comment: One day you will see.

Answer (score -1):

I hope the following example code is helpful for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 4
#define MAX_COLUMS 5

struct maze {
    char *mazeValue;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows, numcolumns;
    int initdir;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    struct maze m;
    char aMazeValue[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMS] = {0};

    m.mazeValue = &aMazeValue[0][0];

    aMazeValue[0][1] = 1;
    aMazeValue[3][2] = 1;

    printf("aMazeValue[0][1] = %d\n", *(m.mazeValue + 1));
    printf("aMazeValue[3][2] = %d\n", *(m.mazeValue + 3 * MAX_COLUMS +2));

    printf("aMazeValue[2][3] = %d\n", aMazeValue[2][3]);
    *(m.mazeValue + 2 * MAX_COLUMS + 3) = 1;
    printf("aMazeValue[2][3] = %d\n", aMazeValue[2][3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants a way to store cost associated with every location on the maze.